# ASP Core - jquery always returning data-url from first clicked control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, popup, partial-views

On my webpage I want to use some sort of a generic popup control so I can use it throughout the site (loaded in partial views). For this a have the folowing code in the _Layout:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalGeneric" role="dialog">
</div>

<script>
function showGenericModal() {
    // get the event source
    event = event || window.event;
    var src = event.target || event.srcElement;

    // find the parent that contains proper decorations
    var url = $(src).closest("*[data-url]").data('url');

    // trigger an HTTP GET
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        // fill content and show modal
        $('#modalGeneric').html(data);
        $('#modalGeneric').modal('show');

    });
}
</script>
```

I then use data-url attribute and showGenericModal() in controls from which I want to show a popup. And this works fine, but not in table rows. For example, if I put an icon at the end of a table row like this:

```html
<td>
    <a class="ml-1" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" 
       data-url="@Url.Action("DeletePartial", "Clients", new { id = @client.IdClient })" 
       onclick="showGenericModal();">

        <svg id="delete" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19" height="21" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-miterlimit="1.41" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round"> 
            <path class="table-icon" d="M17.08 7.4h-1.25v12.1c0 .7-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25H3.75c-.7 0-1.25-.56-1.25-1.25V7.4H1.25C.55 7.4 0 6.86 0 6.17c0-.7.56-1.25 1.25-1.25H5C5 2.6 6.87.76 9.17.76s4.16 1.86 4.16 4.16h3.75c.7 0 1.25.57 1.25 1.26 0 .7-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25zM8.33 18.26H10v-10H8.33v10zM5 8.26v10h1.67v-10H5zM9.17 2.4c-1.38 0-2.5 1.13-2.5 2.5h5c0-1.37-1.12-2.5-2.5-2.5zm4.16 5.85h-1.66v10h1.66v-10z" />
        </svg>
    </a>

</td>
```

the first time a click a row, popup (url) works as expected (lets say it was '/Clients/DeletePartial/1'), but after closing the popup and clicking on any other row will always result in the same data-url being passed (Clients/DeletePartial/1).

Also I checked the generated html and all the 'data-url' are correct:

```html
<a class="ml-1" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" 
    data-url="/Clients/DeletePartial/1" onclick="showGenericModal();">
    <svg id="delete" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19" height="21" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-miterlimit="1.41" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path class="table-icon" d="M17.08 7.4h-1.25v12.1c0 .7-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25H3.75c-.7 0-1.25-.56-1.25-1.25V7.4H1.25C.55 7.4 0 6.86 0 6.17c0-.7.56-1.25 1.25-1.25H5C5 2.6 6.87.76 9.17.76s4.16 1.86 4.16 4.16h3.75c.7 0 1.25.57 1.25 1.26 0 .7-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25zM8.33 18.26H10v-10H8.33v10zM5 8.26v10h1.67v-10H5zM9.17 2.4c-1.38 0-2.5 1.13-2.5 2.5h5c0-1.37-1.12-2.5-2.5-2.5zm4.16 5.85h-1.66v10h1.66v-10z" />
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="ml-1" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" 
    data-url="/Clients/DeletePartial/2" onclick="showGenericModal();">
    <svg id="delete" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19" height="21" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-miterlimit="1.41" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path class="table-icon" d="M17.08 7.4h-1.25v12.1c0 .7-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25H3.75c-.7 0-1.25-.56-1.25-1.25V7.4H1.25C.55 7.4 0 6.86 0 6.17c0-.7.56-1.25 1.25-1.25H5C5 2.6 6.87.76 9.17.76s4.16 1.86 4.16 4.16h3.75c.7 0 1.25.57 1.25 1.26 0 .7-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25zM8.33 18.26H10v-10H8.33v10zM5 8.26v10h1.67v-10H5zM9.17 2.4c-1.38 0-2.5 1.13-2.5 2.5h5c0-1.37-1.12-2.5-2.5-2.5zm4.16 5.85h-1.66v10h1.66v-10z" />
    </svg>
</a>

<a class="ml-1" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" 
    data-url="/Clients/DeletePartial/3" onclick="showGenericModal();">
    <svg id="delete" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="19" height="21" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-miterlimit="1.41" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round">
        <path class="table-icon" d="M17.08 7.4h-1.25v12.1c0 .7-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25H3.75c-.7 0-1.25-.56-1.25-1.25V7.4H1.25C.55 7.4 0 6.86 0 6.17c0-.7.56-1.25 1.25-1.25H5C5 2.6 6.87.76 9.17.76s4.16 1.86 4.16 4.16h3.75c.7 0 1.25.57 1.25 1.26 0 .7-.56 1.25-1.25 1.25zM8.33 18.26H10v-10H8.33v10zM5 8.26v10h1.67v-10H5zM9.17 2.4c-1.38 0-2.5 1.13-2.5 2.5h5c0-1.37-1.12-2.5-2.5-2.5zm4.16 5.85h-1.66v10h1.66v-10z" />
    </svg>
</a>

etc.
```

...so how come I always get the url of the first clicked control (until complete page refresh/reload)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actual answer to "Why this happens?**

At line

```
event = event || window.event;
```

global variable `event` is created and `window.event` is assigned to it. During subsequent calls of the handler the `event` variable is already set with first clicked element reference and therefore this line doesn't change `event` value (because `event` is not empty this time and the expression will return its value). The easiest fix would be to change this code to the following

```
var event = window.event;
```

**Other possible solutions**

Accodring to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)

> The read-only Window property event returns the Event which is currently being handled by the site's code. Outside the context of an event handler, the value is always undefined.
>
> **You should avoid using this property in new code, and should instead use the Event passed into the event handler function**. This property is not universally supported and even when supported introduces potential fragility to your code.

So you shouldn't use `window.event` magic and just `event` object to event handler

**JS**

```
function showGenericModal(event) {
    var src = event.target || event.srcElement;

    // find the parent that contains proper decorations
    var url = $(src).closest("*[data-url]").data('url');

    // trigger an HTTP GET
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        // fill content and show modal
        $('#modalGeneric').html(data);
        $('#modalGeneric').modal('show');

    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
onclick="showGenericModal(event);"
```

**Solution with `this`**

Another solution would be passing `this` to event handler since it handles click on the element contains needed data

**JS**

```
function showGenericModal(anchor) {
     var url = $(anchor).data('url');

    // trigger an HTTP GET
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        // fill content and show modal
        $('#modalGeneric').html(data);
        $('#modalGeneric').modal('show');

    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
onclick="showGenericModal(this);"
```